# How strong a transformer do I need to convert from 220V to 11V at 1.6A?

Tags: transformer, ac

I have a (cordless drill) battery charger that has these specs on its back:

```
INPUT: 120VAC ~ 60Hz 26W
OUTPUT: 3.6V - 10.8V DC, 1.5A
```

Where I live the wall electricity is ~220VAC so I thought a small step down transformer (converter?) from 220V AC to 110V AC that outputs (?) **30W** should work with my charger.

I went to an electronics store and the owner did some math around the 1.5A figure and told me I'd need a much bigger transformer capable of putting out at least **150W** or so.

Is the store guy right? What's the math that he did in his head? And why does my charger show 26W on the back?

Comment: about a tenth of a liter in volume

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, a 30W step-down transformer should be fine. I suspect that the person at the electronics store was multiplying the **input** voltage by the **output** current, which is not the right thing to do.

Edit: Watt's Law says that power is equal to the product of voltage and current. (We will ignore the issues of reactive power and power factor for this simple case.)
$$ P = V \times I $$

On the output side of your charger the nameplate says that the maximum **output** voltage is 10.8V and the maximum **output** current is 1.5A. So, the maximum power **out** of the charger is 16.2W (watts).

On the input side you are given voltage and power, so we can calculate the current:
$$I_{IN} = \frac{P_{IN}}{V_{IN}} = \frac{26}{120} = 217\,\textrm{mA}$$

Thermodynamics tells us that the power out can never be greater than the power in, and in this case we see that this is true.

Comment: Thank you :) Can you point me in the direction of an online explanation of the relevant formula?

Comment: Google "[Ohm's Law](http://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/DC/DC_2.html)" for a full explanation.

Comment: @rdtsc Actually, no, this is not related to Ohm's Law, it is related to Watt's Law.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson true, but Ohm's law leads directly into Watt's Law.

Comment: Transformers have equivalence of power on their inputs and outputs. If voltage goes up, then current goes down and vice versa.

Comment: @Kripacharya Well, **almost** equivalence for a good transformer. In any event, the question was about power ratings for the **charger**.

Comment: Watt was a steam engineer and didn't establish any relationship between power, voltage and current as far as I know. Should it be called "the watt law" or "watts law" without the apostrophe and lower case as per SI standard on units named after a person? Or should it get a capital letter because it's now a proper noun as in "The Watt Law" or "The Watts Law"? What a worry!

Comment: @Elliot Alderson  well since we are nit-picking, actually the question is about the transformer. I was keeping it simple considering the type of question asked.